# Override the taxonomy pages

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming

In Drupal 7, you can use **taxonomy-term.tpl.php** to override taxonomy pages.

Inside the taxonomy-term.tpl.php page, you can use `<?php print $term->field_NAME['und'][0]['value'];?>`to print out the content of any fields attached to the taxonomy term. (*)

However, how do you get to the list of nodes that is displayed on the taxonomy page?

There doesn't seem to be anything in the taxonomy-term.tpl.php file to indicate how to theme the nodes that are displayed on the term page.

I know you can use Views to over ride the page. However, Views does not let you display nodes tagged with a term and fields that are attached to the term in a single View.

(*) I know you are [not supposed to use UND](http://www.davereid.net/content/hlkd7fotw-field-get-items). However, the correct method for access node based fields does not seem to work with taxonomy based fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template file you want to use is not taxonomy-term.tpl.php; that's used for the taxonomy header at the top of the page. The template file used is node.tpl.php.

If you look at [taxonomy_term_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.pages.inc/function/taxonomy_term_page/7) which is used to build the term page view, you will see the nodes are build separately by calling [node_view_multiple()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view_multiple/7). `node_view_multiple()` is just a wrapper for [node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view/7), which uses the standard [node.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.tpl.php/7) file.

Also you should be able to use `field_get_items()` for taxonomy terms. I'll look for something like `$field = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_name');`.

I haven't tried but it should work.

You should really never use `'und'`, but the constant [LANGUAGE_NONE](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7).

Comment: Thank you for your kindness in replying! If I use a custom node.tpl.php file it affects all nodes and not just those displayed on mysite.com/taxonomy/term/[tid]. Is there a way to specify a template just to hide the nodes on the taxonomy index page? I know I can hide all the fields for teaser display  on the manage display tab of the admin interface, but I would like to do it at theme layer.                          Also the $field code you posted on prints out the words "Array". How do I make it display the value in the array?